# Using fake-video in plugins I can't using two video in a test flow in cypress

Tags: browser, plugins, cypress

i have two cameras in a test flow.
Videos and must go through both with different
Using fake-video in plugins I can fake the camera but I can't change the video.

and I must go through both cameras with different videos  in a single spec.js

Could you help me to use two videos in a single spec.js, both videos can be played, I can change what video I play in which camera?

*Plugins/index.js*

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {

  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
    // args.push('--use-fake-device-for-media-stream')
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      args.push('--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream')
      args.push('--use-fake-device-for-media-stream')
     args.push('--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=C:\\NOEMI\\EjemploWebcam\\webcam-tests\\cypress\\fixtures\\akiyo_cif.y4m')  
      //args.push('--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=C:\\NOEMI\\onboardingRepos\\onboarding-web\\cypress\\fixtures\\prueba.y4m')
    }

    return args



  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to change the video source at runtime by using the [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task) command and replacing the content of the file passed through  `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture`. The tricky part of it is that as described [here](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/testing/) you will need to call `getUserMedia()` again after replacing the file.

```
// cypress.config.js
  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    on("before:browser:launch", (browser, launchOptions) => {
      if (browser.family === "chromium" && browser.name !== "electron") {
        const videoPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "cypress", "fixtures", "webcam.y4m");

        launchOptions.args.push(`--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=${videoPath}`);
      }

      return launchOptions;
    });

    on("task", {
      changeVideoSource(videoSource) {
        console.log("TASK - Changing video source to", videoSource);

        const webcamPath = path.join("cypress", "fixtures", "webcam.y4m");
        const sourceVideoPath = path.join("cypress", "fixtures", videoSource);

        const video = fs.readFileSync(sourceVideoPath);

        fs.writeFileSync(webcamPath, video);

        return null;
      },
      resetVideoSource() {
        console.log("TASK - Resetting video source");
        const webcamPath = path.join("cypress", "fixtures", "webcam.y4m");
        const defaultVideoPath = path.join("cypress", "fixtures", "default.y4m");

        const video = fs.readFileSync(defaultVideoPath);

        fs.writeFileSync(webcamPath, video);

        return null;
      },
    });
  },
```

Then everytime you want to change the video just call `cy.task("changeVideoSource", "video2.y4m");`